# What do you call those fenced grassy areas that people own in the countryside?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Example:

[image: A grassy bit of land with a post-and-wire fence delineating the near side, and a row of trees marking another boundary. There's a dirt road along the outside of the fence, and a car parked a bit further on.]

I thought of *fenced plot* or *land lot*, but I'm not sure. They are usually used for farming or raising livestock, but sometimes for nothing at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use *field* (see [Google definition](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=field%20definition%20)).

Comment: +1 In the British Isles these are almost always referred to as *fields*

Answer (score 4):

[Pasture](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pasture): land or a plot of land used for grazing

Answer (score 3):

Sward, field, plot, pasture, meadow, acreage